# What does a GQL Query Return

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I have been working on a project using Google App Engine.  I have been setting up users and have to check if a username is taken yet.
I used the following code to try to test whether it is taken or not

```
usernames = db.GqlQuery('select username from User') 
taken = username in usernames
```

This never caught duplicate usernames.  I tried a few variants of this on the GQL query line. I tried using `.get()` which caused an error because it returned something that wasn't iterable.  I also tried putting `list()` around the request, which returned the same error.  I tried writing the value of `usernames` but never got any response.  If it returns a query instance, then is there any way to turn it into a list or tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you should revisit the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass?hl=en

`db.GqlQuery('select username from User')` is calling a constructor not a function so it returns an instance of a `GqlQuery` object. See docs referred to above.

Secondly what you are doing will never work reliably due to eventual consistancy . Please read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency to understand why.

Lastly you are starting out with appengine, so move away from `db` and use `ndb` unless you have a significant existing code base.